# Find all keys with the max same value in python

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, max

Hi I have a dictionary like the below:

```
b = {'tat': 0, 'del': 4, 'galadriel': 0, 'sire': 0, 'caulimovirus': 4, 'retrofit': 0, 'tork': 0, 'caulimoviridae_dom2': 0, 'reina': 4, 'oryco': 2, 'cavemovirus': 1, 'soymovrius': 0, 'badnavirus': 0, 'crm': 0, 'athila': 0}
```

I want to find all keys with the maximum value as a list. However,

```
max(a, key=a.get)
```

only gives the first key element, 'del'.

How should I find all the keys with the maximum values? Like the below.

```
new_list = ['del', 'caulimovirus', 'reina']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
maxv = max(b.values())
new_list = [k for k, v in b.items() if v == maxv]
```